# Image embedded on button wont show

Tags: java, image, button, javafx

I am trying to Create a button with an embedded image that is 48 x 48 appearing on the left hand side but apparently i am doing something incorrectly because i keep getting 3 .So my question is how can i properly get my image to display? Here is what i have.

```
    Image buttonIcon = new Image("C:/Users/emanu_000/Documents/Excersise4/src/my-profile-icon.png");
    ImageView iconView = new ImageView(buttonIcon);

    getPicButton = new Button("Get Picture",iconView);
    getPicButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
    mainPane.setConstraints(getPicButton, 1, 3);
    mainPane.getChildren().add(getPicButton);
```

This is the stack trace

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in        Application start method
at       com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2/2093176254.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown  protocol: c
 at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1102)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:608)
at com.company.Main.start(Main.java:134)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/135888596.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1904663592.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1835699047.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/2102390814.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/216334026.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1096)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace, and identify the line that throws the exception.

Comment: and how about just posting the relevant code.

Comment: And I assume line 134 is where you create the image...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs for `Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-), the parameter you pass is

> the string representing the URL to use in fetching the pixel data

i.e. you need a URL here, not a file system path.

You can do

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/emanu_000/Documents/Excersise4/src/my-profile-icon.png");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
```

(and I think, more simply, `new Image(file.toURI().toString())` works too).